# Hub / HubSection in Windows 10 Mobile

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-10-mobile

I try to migrate my Windows 8.1 application to Windows 10 Mobile (SDK 10240), 
But the Hub control doesn't work like in Windows Phone 8.1.

The hub sections are too small or big and don't fit the mobile screen width.

I didn't find any property to solve the problem.

```
<Hub Background="White" Header="Header">

    <HubSection x:Uid="HubSection1" Header="Header1">
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="Content1" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </HubSection>
    <HubSection x:Uid="HubSection2" Header="Header2" >
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="Content2" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </HubSection>
</Hub>
```

[image]

I want it like in Windows Phone 8.1 that the Header1 is in the first page, Header2 in the second, etc...

Comment: @JustinXL Has this problem been solved? I am facing it too. What the OP means is that in the old Hub control for mobile the hub sections used to automatically get the width of the screen (minus something to allow the next section to be visible). While now they don't. Also now they don't recycle from last to first like they used to. I believe I can solve the first problem but not the second.

Answer (score 0):

I created [this Behavior](https://github.com/corcus/HubSection-FillPage-Behavior/tree/master) to make the Hub control behave like the Windows Phone 8.1 control when running on mobile.

Check it out and tell me if it fixes your problem.